# iperfのスループット測定結果を比較し、差が大きかった時に速度低下の通知を出したい

Tags: bash

2つのノードに対するiperfのスループット測定結果を比較し、差が2割以上だった時に通知を出したいと考えています。

・スループット測定の結果から、スループット測定の結果の数字（ここでは20.2と10.2）のみを抜き出す方法
・抜き出した数値を計算する方法

の２点についてご教示願えませんでしょうか。

書けるところまで書いてみたソースは、下記の通りです。

```
#!/bin/sh

# スループット測定１
echo "TCP_DL 01"
iperf -c 10.242.23.199 -i 1 -t 5 -f m  >> TCPDL1.txt
tail -n 1 TCPDL.txt
tail -n 1 TCPDL.txt >> throughput1

# スループット測定2
echo "TCP_DL 02"
iperf -c 10.242.23.200 -i 1 -t 5 -f m >> TCPDL2.txt
tail -n 1 TCPDL2.txt
tail -n 1 TCPDL2.txt　>> throughput2

#測定結果の比較
if (throughput1)*0.8 > throughput2 
then 
echo "スループット低下"
else
echo ""
fi
```

実行結果です。

```
TCP_DL 01
[  4]  0.0- 5.1 sec  11896 MBytes  19393 Mbits/sec
TCP_DL 02
[  4]  0.0- 5.0 sec  12490 MBytes  20952 Mbits/sec
iperf.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `0.8'
iperf.sh: line 20: `if (throughput1)0.8 > throughput2'
```

Comment: bash では実数計算ができません。また、実数値の比較もできません。bc コマンドなどを使われた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: iperfの出力フォーマットは数値によってMbpsやGbpsなど自動で変わるので、比較するには表示をパースして単位をそろえる必要があります。オプションで単位を固定できますが、出力が保存されていたりするところを見ると、オプションを指定してよいものか判断しかねます。あと、iperfは実際にそれなりの量のデータを流してスループットを計算しますので、本来業務の通信のスループットに影響したり、トラブルでスループットが落ちてるときにダメ押しになる可能性がありますが、そのあたりは認識されていますか？

Comment: bashでは実数計算ができないのですね・・・。他のコマンドに渡す方法を考えないといけませんか。。。

Comment: オプション指定ができるのですね。出力のフォーマットをMbpsにそろえることは問題ないので、指定するように変えてみました。

はい、iPerfが負荷がかかることは理解した上での試験になりますので、問題ございません。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

必要最小限の改変版です

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# スループット測定１
echo "TCP_DL 01"
iperf -c 10.242.23.199 -i 1 -t 5 -f m  >> TCPDL1.txt
tail -n 1 TCPDL.txt
throughput1=`tail -n 1 TCPDL.txt | sed 's/^.* \([[:digit:]]*\) Mbits\/sec$/\1/'`

# スループット測定2
echo "TCP_DL 02"
iperf -c 10.242.23.200 -i 1 -t 5 -f m >> TCPDL2.txt
tail -n 1 TCPDL2.txt
throughput2=`tail -n 1 TCPDL2.txt | sed 's/^.* \([[:digit:]]*\) Mbits\/sec$/\1/'`

#測定結果の比較
if expr $throughput1 \* 8 \> $throughput2 \* 10 > /dev/null
then 
echo "スループット低下"
else
echo ""
fi
```

- スループットが極端に低下してkbpsオーダーになった
- iperfが異常終了した

などの状況には対応してません。